# Joining tables with different value prefix

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to `join` two tables but the problem is that in the second table the value that is the same as in table one has a prefix to it(this tables are generated after **opencart** instalation - demo data):

```
Table 1: category
 -----------------------------
| category_id | category_name |
|-----------------------------|
|     1       |  Components   |
|     2       |    Laptops    |


Table 2: seo_url
 ------------------------------------------
| seo_url_id  |    query      |   keyword  |
|------------------------------------------|
|     35      | category_id=1 | components |
|     78      | category_id=2 | laptops    |
```

So the id of a category is in column `category_id` in **Table 1** and it is a number but in **Table 2** it is in column `query` and it has a prefix of `category_id=` and then the id `x`(in case of category laptops x being 2).

Can somebody please help me understand how i could join this tables in this situation?

So far i was trying to add `category_id=` + like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.category_name, b.query 
FROM category AS a
INNER JOIN seo_url AS b
ON a.category_id = 'category_id=' + b.query
```

P.S I tried `ON 'category_id=' + a.category_id`

P.S.S There are also `product_id` so i don't know if i could use `LIKE` but i was thinking about it, searched for it and couldn't find a way to make it work.

Thank you! D:

Comment: Seriously consider fixing your design.

Comment: You're directing your murderous intent at the wrong target

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, use the function `CONCAT(...)` that can append strings and numbers, and it is compatible with different versions of that database.

Your fixed query would be:

```
SELECT a.id, a.category_name, b.query 
FROM category AS a
INNER JOIN seo_url AS b
ON CONCAT('category_id=', a.category_id) = b.query;
```

Your table `seo_url` already has the 'category_id=' in the values of the field `query`, so you don't need to append it.

Additionally, I'd recommend you to name the table aliases with more representative names, instead of using `a` and `b`.

Hope this helps you to solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Use nested `REVERSE` functions with `+ 0` to autocast "parse" out the integer.

**Query**

```
SELECT
 REVERSE(REVERSE('category_id=2') + 0)
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
 REVERSE(REVERSE('category_id=21') + 0)
```

**Result**

```
| REVERSE(REVERSE('category_id=2') + 0) |
|---------------------------------------|
|                                     2 |
|                                    21 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/530

Use it in your query.

**Query**

```
SELECT a.category_id, a.category_name, b.query 
FROM category AS a
INNER JOIN seo_url AS b
ON a.category_id = REVERSE(REVERSE(b.query) + 0)
```

**Result**

```
| category_id | category_name |         query |
|-------------|---------------|---------------|
|           1 |    Components | category_id=1 |
|           2 |       Laptops | category_id=2 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef5781/1

Comment: Hey @RaymondNijland, thank you for answering, but can you please explain how that reverse thingie works cause now i'm even more blown away :O

Comment: "but can you please explain how that reverse thingie works cause now i'm even more blown away :" Sure check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d76e50/77 @emma

Comment: Heeey @RaymondNijland, i've implemented this and for some reason some categories appear twice. Hmm, am i doing something wrong? :-s 
P.S i have a total of 38 categories and using this method(reverse) i get 51 - some of them, of course, are just a double